# Trying to understand Java I/O and streams

Tags: java, io, stream, inputstream, outputstream

Very new to coding and Java, and I'm trying to wrap my head around streams.

My textbook says that "a stream is linked to a physical device by the Java I/O system." What do they mean when they say "physical"? I've also seen the word used to describe *code* instead of an actual physical thing that one can see and touch.

When they say a stream is linked to a physical device, do they mean an actual thing you can hold, or something that exists in memory, like an object? Google isn't helping me much with this, saying things like "A Stream is linked to a physical layer", and I'm not sure what that means either.

Comment: Every aspect of a program is ultimately "linked to a physical device", be it memory a disk drive, or something else. The important thing about Streams is understanding the abstraction and how to use it. I don't think focussing on that vague sentence is useful.

Comment: (and don't get confused between `java.util.stream` and `InputStream` and `OutputStream`, which may be what your textbook is referring to!

Comment: Of course an `InputStream` can also be linked to a `byte[]` -- whether that's a "physical device" is unclear.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with writing code in Java or with the Java programming language. The term "physical" here is used in a standard computer science meaning that has nothing to do with actually writing code. The question is about hardware and computer design, not programming; it is off topic here. You may have better luck with e.g. [cs.se].

Comment: I understand your confusion. “Stream” is used in a lot of ways and meanings in computing, and “physical” is too. In this case they mean a physical disc or other device as opposed to the stream as a more conceptual way to look at the data held on the disk. Also I changed the java-stream tag on your question to some more correct ones since java-stream is for the Java stream API which is not for input or output and hence not relevant here.

Comment: @tgdavies In my mind that’s clear enough: a byte array is not in itself physical but is backed by physical storage/memory.

Comment: @OleV.V. True of a file too. And a TCP/IP socket.

Comment: @tgdavies Very true. Your first comment was to the point. And there can be several, even very many layers of abstraction between some programming concept and the metal underneath. (And saying “underneath” here is an abstraction too.)

Comment: Wow! Thank you, everyone! I really appreciate all the responses. I even asked someone who's more familiar with coding than I am and they said they'd never heard of "physical" used like this before. But it's been cleared up now, thanks to everyone here! Thank you also for changing up the tags, @OleV.V.! I'm so new to this that I often am not sure what to ask, how to ask it, or where to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your book is probably outdated.

Java has had the `java.io.InputStream` interface for about 30 years. That's what it is referring to, but is incorrect.

Java also has the `java.util.stream.Stream` stream which is *completely unrelated* and also uses that word.

### InputStream

InputStream is an abstract concept representing a *readable stream of bytes*. By design this stream is not (necessarily) kept in memory. For example, you can turn a file into such a thing, and it doesn't matter if that file is absolutely gigantic. You can simply check the [javadoc of `InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/io/InputStream.html) for more.

Given that it is an interface, you can implement one if you want. Java has many of them baked into the core libraries, and there are hundreds more in commonly used third party libraries.

They are often used for e.g. files, network connections, and database blobs. Whether you feel that is 'physical'.. now we're just mincing words, I'm not sure it's useful. Point is, the tutorial/document you are reading decided to clarify matters by using that term and I think that was a really bad idea. It clarifies very little. In fact, it's essentially hogwash - there is no need for an inputstream to be backed by a physical device at all. Here:

```
byte[] data = new byte[] {1, 2, 3, 4};
InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);
```

Voila. I made an input stream that is most definitely not backed by anything physical. Or, if 'well, that array is in RAM so I guess that counts' is the line of thinking, then a String is also backed by 'something physical' and in fact everything in java is. Either way, that statement is either incorrect or highly misleading.

Nevertheless, InputStream is designed to deal with 'physical-ish' concepts.

For example, whether we are talking about spinning platters or cells in an SSD, both of them are fundamentally incapable of giving you a single byte. Instead they give you whole blocks worth.

Hence, the API of InputStream is a bit weird - you can ask it for 1 byte, or, you can provide it a  byte array and ask it to fill it 'up as far as the input stream feels is efficient'. For example, given a file with 1GB of data left to read, if you hand it a 100MB byte array, the API is free to fill 20MB worth, tell you it gave you 20MB, and return. Even though it could fill 80 more MB.

Because perhaps that was 'most efficient' - it depends on the hardware, and the *entire point* of `InputStream` is that it abstracts this stuff away.

The book / tutorial / that google result is making a very common explanatory mistake, which is that they have a word, they think everybody assumes that word means what the author thinks it means, and then just uses the word without explaining it.

No such luck - many words are either straight up ambiguous (in that there are entire culture wars fought over its meaning), or only clear in the sense that 'jargon is clear' - **if** you know what a 'stream' is in java jargon, then you... know what a stream is. Either way, presuming that the reader knows the jargon when you are trying to explain the basics is didactically speaking of course utterly daft. And yet it sounds like your tutorial or what not made that mistake. Probably best to toss it out, or at least keep in mind it's not doing a very good job.

At any rate, what *the author* feels the word 'physical' means is:

- A file on disk/ssd.
- A blob in a database.
- One side of a TCP/IP network connection (the 'data flowing from whomever you are talking to, to your application. For example, if requesting a web page, the HTTP return headers and, say, the HTML).

Which isn't clear, but even if we take that as read, it's wrong in that you can also make an InputStream for something as simple as a byte array.

### The `java.util.stream.Stream` sense

This is a different 'take' on the notion of a collection, such as a list. It has absolutely nothing to do with files and networks and is a similar *highly* abstract idea. `InputStream` is a stream of bytes, and the API exposes various ways of grabbing them in bulk for efficiency reasons. `j.u.s.Stream` is a stream of Ts - as in, pick a type, it can be a stream of strings, bytes, persons, students, horses, computers, videos, messages, songs, or whatever you want. It doesn't have bulk methods "for efficiency", it has bulk methods for readability. Other than the notion that the english dictionary word 'stream' feels like a decent fit for both of them, there is *absolutely no relation between the two*.

Further highlighting one clear conclusion: The tutorial / book you are reading is trying to clarify things. It missed the mark. By quite a few ballparks.

Comment: I hope my textbook isn't outdated, it's the 2022 edition... If things update that fast, then I'm in real trouble!

I see that the word "physical" is causing a LOT of trouble. Some people I spoke to hadn't even heard of the term used in that sense before. But thank you! I run into a lot of walls where I'm not familiar with any of the jargon, and then I have to swerve around to find out what all of it means before I can make sense of the original concept.

Comment: It's didactically at best 'suboptimal'. 'crappy writing' is probably a more fair name. I presume that's 'we have updated it in 2022', and they incorrectly thought that wording didn't need updating now that `java.util.stream.Stream` exists. Note that there is "slang jargon", which is a term of art that some people are vehemently believing means X, but others do not. It's still jargon, in that X is paragraphs+ so you need SOME word for it. There's also "official jargon", where effectively everybody agrees on the precise meaning.

Comment: "Official jargon" generally gets its blessings because thats the term used in official specs and docs, such as 'method' being official jargon. Point is 'physical' here is straight up incorrect (it's conflating what InputStreams are usually used for and what their spec requires), but insofar that it is trying to be helpful, it's slang jargon. Best not to dwell on slang jargon. Communication is the job of transferring thought from one brain to another. If the word/paper/voice/speakers/screen aren't doing a good job at this, ditch the tool, don't fight about it.

Comment: Understood! Thank you so much. I'll keep that in mind as I keep studying!

Answer (score 1):

When it refers to a "physical layer", it's just saying that somewhere down the line the Stream reaches something you can actually touch (i.e. physical). Take `FileInputStream`, for example.

To most people, a file is just something stored on their computer and is considered to be digital. But when you use the `FileInputStream` in Java, somewhere down the line it gets to your physical storage device (hard drive, solid state drive, etc) where the input is actually being stored.

Comment: Your explanation begs the question: Can you name something that happens in programming, that is not reaching a "physical layer"? See [tgdavies' comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75910012/trying-to-understand-java-i-o-and-streams#comment133892227_75910012).